# client.ExecuteAsync<T> Delegate does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to change my Restsharp Client to work `async` instead of `sync`. 
Each of my API-Calls referes to the `GetAsync<T>` method. When I try now to change the Client to call `ExecuteAsync<T>` instead of `Execute` i got this error:

> Delegate 'Action, RestRequestAsyncHandle>' does not take 1 Arguments

I'm using RestSharp Version 106.6.10 currently.

Here is my GetAsyncMethod:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs = null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check token is expired
            DateTime expires = DateTime.Parse(Account.Properties[".expires"]);
            if (expires < DateTime.Now)
            {
                // Get new Token 
                await GetRefreshTokenAsync();
            }

            // Get AccessToken
            string token = Account.Properties["access_token"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                throw new NullReferenceException("AccessToken is null or empty!");

            // Create client
            var client = new RestClient()
            {
                Timeout = 3000000
            };

            //Create Request
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            // Add Parameter when necessary 
            if (keyValuePairs != null)
            {
                foreach (var pair in keyValuePairs)
                {
                    request.AddParameter(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
            }
            // Call
            var result = default(T);

            var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
            {
                // check respone 
                if (restResponse.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
                {
                    result = restResponse.Data;
                }

                //else
                //    throw new Exception("Call stopped with Status: " + response.StatusCode +
                //                        " Description: " + response.StatusDescription);
            });

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

Here one of the calling Methods:

```
public async Task<List<UcAudit>> GetAuditByHierarchyID(int hierarchyID)
    {
        string url = AuthSettings.ApiUrl + "/ApiMethod/" + hierarchyID;

        List<UcAudit> auditList = await GetAsync<List<UcAudit>>(url);
        return auditList;
    }
```

When I Change the `T` in `ExecuteAsync<T>` in one of my classes the error is gone. How can I change the method to work `async` with `<T>`???

Comment: The delegate to ExecuteAsync<T> takes 2 parameters, you're only passing 1, that's what the error message states. Why do you want to use the generic overload?

Comment: I want to use it, because i have a ton of API-Methods and want one generic call for all of them. How do I pass the second Parameter? This are two Parameter or I'm wrong? (request, restResponse => {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the info from Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen I found the solution.

This is the start:

```
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
        {
            // check respone 
            if (restResponse.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
            {
                result = restResponse.Data;
            }

            //else
            //    throw new Exception("Call stopped with Status: " + response.StatusCode +
            //                        " Description: " + response.StatusDescription);
        });
```

Worked for me :

```
client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response, asyncHandle )=>
            {
                //check respone
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    result = response.Data;
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Call stopped with Status: " + response.StatusCode +
                                        " Description: " + response.StatusDescription);
            });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that this method is marked as obsolete in the latest version. The whole thing will be changed moving forward to use proper async calls with `HttpWebRequest`